# Capture which li a class is attached to

Tags: sass, mixins

I am not sure if this is possible, but is there a way for sass to identify which li a particular class is attached to?

If I had:

```
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="Selected"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
```

And I'm trying to get a mixin to switch a CSS property based on where the "Selected" class is located. So something like:

```
ul li { background: url(@include(mixin));  }

$Names:("../Images/One.png","../Images/Two.png","../Images/Three.png","../Images/Four.png","../Images/Five.png",)

@include mixin($Names){
    @each $liindex in $Names{
    $i: index($Names, $liindex );

    if(/* see if this li has class Selected */){
      /* change property here?
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable with `nth-of-type`. Something like this:

```
@mixin bg-mixin($Names){
    @each $bg-url in $Names{
        $i: index($Names, $bg-url );
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}).Selected { background: url($bg-url); }
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```
ul li {
    @include bg-mixin($Names);
}
```

resulting in

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1).Selected {
  background: url("../Images/One.png");
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2).Selected {
  background: url("../Images/Two.png");
}
ul li:nth-of-type(3).Selected {
  background: url("../Images/Three.png");
}
ul li:nth-of-type(4).Selected {
  background: url("../Images/Four.png");
}
ul li:nth-of-type(5).Selected {
  background: url("../Images/Five.png");
}
```